# What voltage should I use with this solenoid?

Tags: resistance

I have a solenoid labeled Gottelieb A-1496. It's for pinball machines.

I'm trying to figure out what voltage I can use with it.

It has 23-635 windings and a 2.95 ohms resistance. I don't know the width of the wire.

Answer (score 1):

[Link to info on pinball machines](http://www.pinballmedic.net/coil_chart.html)

Looks like pinball machines use 50Volts DC to operate the solenoids.   I found several places on the internet discussing repair of pinball machines, and 50Volts seems to be the rule.

There are pinball machine solenoids with one coil or two coils.

The solenoids with two coils are used in the flipper arms.  The coil with the lower resistance activates first and slams the flipper into position, then shuts off.  The second coil (which has a higher resistance) is then activated to hold the flipper arm in place.

The single coil solenoids are used in the bumpers or for knockers.

The one you have only has one coil, so I expect this one is used on the bumpers.  You probably shouldn't keep it energized for more than a second or so else will over heat and maybe burn out.  It is only intended to provide a short smack to make the ball move in a different direction.

Answer (score 0):

There is some information on here about pinball coils and voltages used

http://www.pinballmedic.net/coil_chart.html